# expect vs tcl , what is better for automation tasks

Tags: linux, tcl, solaris, expect

I want to make automation script like

1. auto rpm installation
2. long packages installation  ( pkgs list with many question in the progress )
3. auto answering on application installation questions

What is better for this task tcl or expect ?

what is uniq in tcl and better from expect?

Comment: `Expect` is an extension of `Tcl`. You can give a try with [autoexpect](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1865).

Comment: can you give more details?

Comment: What OS, specifically?  Solaris allows for complete automated installation without using add-on tools such as `expect`.  See `man pkgask`, for example (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/pkgask-1m.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expect is actually just Tcl plus a few extra commands (notably `spawn`, `expect` and `send`) and it is *designed* for automating things. Tcl's just a programming language that's designed for making scriptable tools with.

Given that, for automating RPM installation (especially when there's quite a few interactive questions) the right choice is definitely Expect. Just remember: you can use the power of Tcl inside Expect where you need it. You've got a full programming language available to you. That lets you do *really* complicated stuff if you're inventive…

Comment: The one thing that Expect isn't good at is automating GUI applications. It only automates things in terminals.

Comment: you mean that - I can write real tcl command in to expect script inside?

Comment: You can use Tcl commands in an Expect script. Expect is _exactly_ Tcl plus a package of commands (called Expect) that add the subprocess automation features.